# React App has an error on start after mac update

Tags: node.js, reactjs, macos, npm, react-scripts

I have a mac development computer and after it ran an update, my entire development environment wend down.  I got php amd mysql working again, but react refuses to do so.  When I try running `npm start` I keep getting this error message.

```
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path /Users/[username]/Sites/react-test2
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c react-scripts start
```

This is the entire error as it's in the log.

```
0 verbose cli [
0 verbose cli   '/opt/homebrew/Cellar/node/15.8.0/bin/node',
0 verbose cli   '/opt/homebrew/bin/npm',
0 verbose cli   'start'
0 verbose cli ]
1 info using npm@7.5.4
2 info using node@v15.8.0
3 timing config:load:defaults Completed in 0ms
4 timing config:load:file:/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/npm/npmrc Completed in 1ms
5 timing config:load:builtin Completed in 1ms
6 timing config:load:cli Completed in 0ms
7 timing config:load:env Completed in 0ms
8 timing config:load:file:/Users/[username]/Sites/react-test2/.npmrc Completed in 0ms
9 timing config:load:project Completed in 1ms
10 timing config:load:file:/Users/[username]/.npmrc Completed in 0ms
11 timing config:load:user Completed in 0ms
12 timing config:load:file:/opt/homebrew/etc/npmrc Completed in 0ms
13 timing config:load:global Completed in 0ms
14 timing config:load:cafile Completed in 0ms
15 timing config:load:validate Completed in 0ms
16 timing config:load:setUserAgent Completed in 0ms
17 timing config:load:setEnvs Completed in 0ms
18 timing config:load Completed in 2ms
19 verbose npm-session 735477708cc52a23
20 timing npm:load Completed in 6ms
21 timing command:run-script Completed in 1010ms
22 timing command:start Completed in 1011ms
23 verbose stack Error: command failed
23 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/promise-spawn/index.js:64:27)
23 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:378:20)
23 verbose stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1067:16)
23 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:301:5)
24 verbose pkgid react-test2@0.1.0
25 verbose cwd /Users/[username]/Sites/react-test2
26 verbose Darwin 20.3.0
27 verbose argv "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/node/15.8.0/bin/node" "/opt/homebrew/bin/npm" "start"
28 verbose node v15.8.0
29 verbose npm  v7.5.4
30 error code 1
31 error path /Users/[username]/Sites/react-test2
32 error command failed
33 error command sh -c react-scripts start
34 verbose exit 1
```

As far as I can tell this means it can't find react-scripts.  Which is weird, because when I look at the packages instaled with npm, it's there.

```
npm list
react-test2@0.1.0 /Users/[username]/Sites/react-test2
├── @testing-library/jest-dom@5.11.9
├── @testing-library/react@11.2.5
├── @testing-library/user-event@12.7.1
├── react-dom@17.0.1
├── react-scripts@4.0.2
├── react@17.0.1
└── web-vitals@1.1.0
```

I found several possible fixes online but none of them work. I have even tried them multiple times, in different orders. They including:

- The delete `node_modules` and `package-lock.json` then reinstalling with `npm install`.
- `npm install -g create-react-app`
- `npm install -g react-scripts`
- `npm cache clean --force`
- Uninstalled `node`, `npm`, `react-scripts`, and `create-react-app`.  Rebooted the machine, installed them fresh, and created a new react app.
- creating a new app with `npx create-react-app`

I do not have Yarn, but have been using Homebrew as a package manager.

Comment: What command are you running exactly? `npm start`?

I would like to add that the problem likely is not that it can't find react-scripts, because it says the command failed, not that it cannot find the command.

Comment: It's `npm start`.  I've updated the question with it and the error log.

Comment: I can't make much of it. I think the easiest way to fix this is to create a new app using `npx create-react-app` (using a global install of `create-react-app` is no longer the preferred way to use it, see the docs on this one) and copy the contents of your `src` folder.

Comment: deleting all of your local node modules and running `npm install` again might help...